# Alter application icon to execute command?

Tags: launcher

Is it possible to set the icon for an application, both in the dock and in the Applications launcher, to execute a command?

I need to be able to launch Kodi with the LIRC support for a specific remote at the same time. I can do this from terminal with the command "/usr/bin/kodi --lircdev /var/run/lirc/lircd", which I've also set as a custom command to run at startup. However if I click on the Kodi icon from dock or applications, it doesn't support the remote. So I'm just looking for a way to alter the icon to send that command signal, instead of just launching Kodi on its own.

I tried pinning to dock the instance of Kodi that launches on startup, but it still just launches standard Kodi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using AppEditor to alter or add a .desktop file. Those desktop files control what you see for example in the Applications menu.

Comment: I tried googling for AppEditor but was getting stuff that wasn't useful. The direction prompted by .desktop was useful though, and after a quick google I landed here https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en which gave me enough information to open up the kodi.desktop in nano, duplicate it with a few changes and make an icon called "Kodi with remote" in my applications and dock. Works perfectly, thanks for your reply!

Comment: I meant the app, in the AppCenter: https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor.desktop